# How do I turn off NotifyOSD display of music information? It distracts me from my work

Tags: notify-osd

While writing reports for school (using Writer or Impress), I often play a playlist of instrumental music in the background. It is distracting to have the NotifyOSD pop up every time the song changes. NotifyOSD pops up to show the Artist, Song, etc. It distracts me from my work. I'd like for the playlist to play without NotifyOSD. I prefer to use the Exaile music player.

Can this be natively configured? How do I do it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to tell us which music player you use?

Answer (score 5):

In Exaile: **Edit → Preferences → Plugins → Notify-osd notification**, just "uncheck" everything in **Display** section.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In rhythmbox, if that's what you are using, `Edit > plugins > status icon / tray icon` (can't tell you the exact name, my ubuntu is not configured in english) and in configure you can disable the notifications completely, or set it to only appear when the main window is hidden.

Comment: I use Exaile. Can it be done with Exaile?

Answer (score 0):

There are different notification levels. For instance, when you're watching a movie, then only important/urgent notifications are shown. I *think*, but I do not know, that if you set yourself as busy, then the same thing will happen. In any case, there should be a way to set the notification level you want to receive. We should probably have a good configuration tool for this, but I don't know of any.

Comment: How do I set myself as "busy" with respect to NotifyOSD?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the presence settings in the messaging menu should do that.